# Perl: simple foreach on hash hands mixed results?

Tags: perl, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What decides the order of keys when I print a Perl hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011342/what-decides-the-order-of-keys-when-i-print-a-perl-hash)

Say I got a simple script to list the contents of a hash from a book:

```
my %hash = ("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4);

for my $i (%hash) {
    print $i . "\n";
}
```

On one computer it lists:
`c
3
a
1
b
2
d
4`

But on another it has it proper (in order): `a
1
b
2
c
3
d
4`

Why does it do this? does the foreach list it randomly or is it some random bug? My current (the c-a-b-d one is running Perl 5.10.1 the other 5.6?)