# Why is this hash, created from a constant list, "in different order" each time the program is run?

Tags: perl, hash

Below is the small script in Perl. Every time I run this code I'm getting different output.

Can anyone help me to understand the basics of storage of hash variables, that is how indexing is done for the key value pairs of Perl's hash variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%data = ('John Paul' => 45, 'Lisa' => 30, 'Kumar' => 40);
@names = keys %data;
print "$names[0]\n";
print "$names[1]\n";
print "$names[2]\n";
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting question because of the subtle implication of *what* this means Perl is doing - and why. However, in general, hash order is "not reliable" so while it may expose an interesting artifact, it is doing so under the general "don't do that" category - which is likely the cause of downvote(s).

Comment: Reproducible https://ideone.com/IXwgWz (more names added so the different order is more visible more often)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What decides the order of keys when I print a Perl hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011342/what-decides-the-order-of-keys-when-i-print-a-perl-hash)

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate of that question (of which the answers do cover the "don't do that" category), for reasons previously stated. This is a *specific* situation about *why the order differs between runs* and is tied to a specific implementation detail. This behavior is "relatively new".

Comment: @user2864740, It's actually quite old. It's at least 12 years old since env var `PERL_HASH_SEED` was added in 5.8.1. The only difference is that it now happens more often. It used to be some specific conditions had to happen before a hash would become salted, but now all hashes are salted from the start.

Comment: @ikegami "relatively new" ;-) given the static [although not necessarily bad] changes since Perl 6 was .. uhh, announced. And yes, this dates me quite a bit.. in any case, a bit of new trivia filed.

Answer (score 12):

The behaviour is documented in [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html)'s [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks).

---

A hash is an array of linked lists. A hashing function converts the key into a number which is used as the index of the array element ("bucket") into which to store the value. More than one key can hash to the same index ("collision"), a situation handled by the linked lists.

If a malicious user knew the hashing algorithm, he could devise values that would hash to the same index, causing the hash to degenerate into a linked list. This can lead to *huge* performance drops in some applications, and thus can be used as part of a denial of service (DoS) attack.

Two measures are taken to avoid that. One is to salt the hashing algorithm to randomize the order in which elements are stored, and the other makes it harder to detect the salt by perturbing the order in which the iterator visits the hash elements.

```
$ perl -E'
   my @k = "a".."z";
   for (1..3) {
      my %h = map { $_ => 1 } @k;
      say keys %h;
   }
'
iocmbygdkranwxfejuqpzvltsh
bmcoigdywrankujfxezpqlvths
juexfwarnkgdybmcoihstlvzpq
```

Comment: (The vulnerability mitigated is known as a "Hash [Flood] DoS".)

Comment: Plus ff you *need* order *and* you need a "hash" there's various ways of doing that among which: [`Hash::Ordered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered).

Comment: @ikegami: What perl version you are using? In my system, perl v5.14.2, the ouput is one time `wraxdjyukhgftienvmslcpqbzo` and `wraxdjyukhgftienvmslpcqbzo` two times (or more if I increase the for loop range). Why this happen?

Comment: @cuonglm, You can get different orderings in 5.14 between runs, but some specific conditions have to happen first. The frequency at which you get different orderings changed in 5.18.

Comment: @ikegami: Can you clarify what are `specific conditions`?

Comment: @cuonglm, When a hash becomes degenerate (starts looking too much like a linked list), the salt of the hash's hash algorithm is changed.

Comment: @ikegami: Ah, of course, I know that. I only mean how I can get the different output for each time like yours. I change to perl 5.20 and get the expected output. And after reading the document again, this semantic is with perl 5.18 and above. Older version need setting `PERL_HASH_SEED` and `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS`.

Comment: @cuonglm, No, old version didn't need to set `PERL_HASH_SEED` to enable the salting (it is usually used to *disable* the salting when debugging hashes), and didn't have `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS`.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is described in [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

> Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is specific to a given hash; the exact same series of operations on two hashes may result in a different order for each hash. Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, with the exception that the most recent key returned by each or keys may be deleted without changing the order. So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on keys, values and each to repeatedly return the same order as each other.

.. in order to prevent [`Algorithmic Complexity Attacks`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks)

Comment: The behavior implies that the (re)hash function used by Perl is itself non-deterministic across processes (which is not in conflict with, but not fully covered by, the quote) and should probably be covered in greater detail.

Comment: That passage does not explain why it differs bewteen runs.

Comment: @Сухой27, Rather than replacing everything, I have posted my own answer.

Comment: Correct documentation link: [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks)

Comment: @ikegami tnx for the link.

Comment: Re "in order to", That quoted passage is true even when no measures are taken to prevent the "algorithmic complexity attacks".